# Spring 5.2.1.RELEASE getProperty returns "User" instead of my custom "username=..." property

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, properties, getproperty

I have found out that for some reason

```
dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("username"));
```

returns "User" value instead of my property username=postgres
It is indicated in the HTTP 500 DB connection error

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "User"
```

And if I debug in Intellij Idea, I see that when I execute that string, it ends up with "User" for some reason.
I guess there is some collision of implementation the getProperty() method of the PropertyResolver interface. However, I could not find from where that implementation and collision comes from.

I am learning Spring framework, I watch a video course. The only difference between my and the course project is that I am using the currently latest postgres, thus, pom.xml contains the latest postgres dependency. However, if I change it to the same dependency without reinstalling the postgreSQL to the needed version - I still do not get my property working.

BUT! If I rename the property and I adjust the property name in the getProperty() method, I get it working! For instance, I used "db-username" in my db.property and it worked. Regardless of the matching of the postgreSQL versions. I don't think the DB is the case. I think there is some conflict I can not find yet in the framework. Could you please let me know what could be the reason? For example, I want to use this name on principle - the "username" property naming, so how do I find the root-root cause?

P.S.

The code is below:
SpringConfig:
https://pastebin.com/2n0WHnut

pom.xml
https://pastebin.com/NUBtZEqR

Does not work =>

```
dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("username"));

db.property:

driver=org.postgresql.Driver
url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/first_db
username=postgres
driver=org.postgresql.Driver
url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/first_db
username=postgres
password=FooBaaaaar
```

Works!:

```
dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("db-username"));

db.property:

driver=org.postgresql.Driver
url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/first_db
username=postgres
driver=org.postgresql.Driver
url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/first_db
db-username=postgres
password=FooBaaaaar
```

I have tried to debug it using IDE and I saw that the getProperty method for sure returns in the runtime the value of "User" when I user the "username" property name in the db.property and getProperty() method.

Comment: by the way, in the video from the course, it is working with the "username" naming of the property

Comment: `username` is probably an environment variable which takes precedence of your own value, which is why it works with another propery name. Doesn't matter if works in the video or not as that is a different environment.

Comment: Thank you. I have seen that the MANIFEST.MF contains that Built-By User line. Probably it takes my PC username name also. My PC username is "User". But When I was changing my PC username to somethinglese, the MANIFEST was not updating itself when rebuilding, so I got the same "Built-by User" line and the same error with the auth problem for user "User". Where I can change or see that environamental variable on my PC? I use win10. Is it where the PATH var exists?

Comment: You can run `SET` from the command line to see all the properties. Next to that the JVM also has a property `user.name` which can influence things. Generally it is better to prefix those properties with the use like `jdbc.username` or `datasource.username` so that it has a bit of intend as well and you won't run into the risk of clashing with (or reduce the risk) environment or system variables.

Comment: Yep, that was my SET USERNAME local variable. For some reason, somewhere it is substituted when the property name is "username". Checked on two computers, replicated. Thank you!